# How to set ItemsSource value of ColumnSeries?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I am not able to set `ItemsSource` value of `ColumnSeries`. I am following some examples ([this](http://eren.ws/2013/10/15/using-graphs-and-charts-in-windows-store-apps-boredom-challenge-day-11/) and [this](https://claytonone.wordpress.com/category/c/winrt-xaml-toolkit/)) but they seem to be out dated.

Here is my `XAML`:

```
<Charting:Chart x:Name="ColumnChart"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Width="Auto"
                Height="Auto">
    <Charting:ColumnSeries Title="Georgi Kyuchukov"
                           Margin="0"
                           Name="ColumnChartSeries"
                           IndependentValuePath="Name"
                           DependentValuePath="Pts"
                           IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
</Charting:Chart>
```

and here is my `C#` code:

```
public class ChartData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Pts { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    List<ChartData> personalData = (List<ChartData>)e.Parameter;

    foreach (ChartData x in personalData){
        Debug.WriteLine(x.Name + " " + x.Pts);
    }

    (ColumnChart.Series[0] as ColumnSeries).ItemsSource = personalData;
    //ColumnChartSeries.ItemsSource = personalData;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'ColumnSeries' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have also try:

```
ColumnChartSeries.ItemsSource = personalData;
```

But get:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   gotqn.exe but was not handled in user code.

Also, I am getting the following error often:

> Error 1   A value of type 'ColumnSeries' cannot be added to a collection
>   or dictionary of type 'Collection`1'.

but I am able to run the application, so I guess it is not critical.

Could you tell what I am doing wrong?

Also, I will be grateful for being given some good up-to-dated documentation link/article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're missing this in your code behind...

```
using WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;
```

Try moving your cursor to `ColumnSeries` and press Alt+Shift+F10 to add the missing namespace. Or simply use Alt+Enter if you have ReSharper (which I recommend).